# Obter uma lista de dados mapeados em NHibernate

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

Estou tentando transformar os dados retornados do banco para as configurações feitas em meu mapeamento, porém eu recebo a seguinte critica:

> "**O valor "System.Object[]" não é do tipo "Domain.Classes.ClasseExemplo" e não pode
>   ser usado nesta coleção genérica.**"

Eu já tentei utilizar o **"Transformers.AliasToBen"**, porém percebi que ignora todo o meu mapeamento. Ainda sou muito novo nessa área, se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço.


**Minha Classe:**

```
public class ClasseExemplo
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Descricao { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

**Mapeamento:**

```
    public ClasseExemploMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.ID);
        Map(x => x.Descricao);
        Refereces(x => x.Usuario).Column("USUARIO_ID").Cascade.None();
        Map(x => x.TimeStamp);

        Table("TABELA");
    }
```

**Repositorio:**

```
public IList<ClasseExemplo> BuscarLista(int usuario)
{
    string SQL = "select * " +
     "from MinhaTabela " +
     "where Usuario_ID = :id";

    return Session.CreateSQLQuery(SQL)
           .SetParameter("id", usuario)
           //.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBen(typeof(ClasseExemplo))
           .List<ClasseExemplo>();
}
```

Comment: Não tem o campo Usuario_ID? Pelo menos no seu código de classe e map

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Virgilio, eu tinha esquecido de mencionar o **Column** no meu mapeador, porém o erro ainda persiste.

Comment: Como está essa tabela e um teste tira aquele genérica e verifica o retorno com List ()

Comment: Não conseguir entender muito bem, eu realmente preciso retornar os valores moldado a minha classe, não é possível retorna os valores somente com List().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É sim, eu acabei fazendo um teste e funciona perfeitamente, acho que está fazendo algo de errado, um exemplo para ilustrar:

***Class***

```
public class Credit
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? Created { get; set; }
}
```

***MapClass***

```
public class CreditMap: ClassMap<Credit>
{
    public CreditMap()
    {
        Table("credit");

        Id(x => x.Id)
            .Column("id")
            .GeneratedBy.Sequence("credit_id_seq");

        Map(x => x.Description)
            .Column("description")
            .Length(100)
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.Created)
            .Column("created")
            .Nullable();
    }
}
```

Agora para pesquisar um `id` que vai trazer ***apenas um item***:

```
int id = 1;
var creditFindId = connection
            .CreateSqlQuery("SELECT * FROM credit WHERE id=:id")            
            .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<Credit>())
            .SetParameter("id", id)
            .UniqueResult<Credit>(); // Resultado único
```

ou para filtar pelo um campo especifico para trazer uma lista de item:

```
int id = 1;
var creditFindId = connection
    .CreateSqlQuery("SELECT * FROM credit WHERE id=:id")
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<Credit>())
    .SetParameter("id", id)
    .List<Credit>(); // Lista
```

porque esse tipo de método do `NHibernate` retornar os dados em um *array de objetos* (`object[]`) e não em um tipo fortemente tipado, para isso precisa utilizar:

- `.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<Credit>())` para saber qual tipo de dado deve ser transformado
- `.UniqueResult<Credit>()` ou `.List<Credit>()` para o tipo em especifico forçando a configuração anterior.

Se for para fazer filtros e já tratar os dados com o tipo especifico sem uso de `SQL` pode ser feito assim também:

```
int id = 1;
var item1 = connection.QueryOver<Credit>()
     .And(x => x.Id == id) // filtro
     .SingleOrDefault<Credit>(); // Resultado único
```

---

```
int id = 1;
var list1 = connection.QueryOver<Credit>()
     .And(x => x.Id == id) // filtro
     .List<Credit>(); // Lista
```

<sup>***Observação:*** onde está escrito `//filtro` pode ser colocado outros tantos filtros e ordernação.</sup>

Vale lembrar que se o resultado for pela chave primária se pode fazer assim:

```
int id = 1;
Credit credit = session.Get<Credit>(id);
```

e assim por diante, não é muito difícil depois que pegue os métodos e suas funcionalidades fica tranquilo a manipulação.

Comment: Muito obrigado consegui resolver o problema, por algum motivo eu não consigo retorna a lista com a **CreateSQLQuery**, utilizei o exemplo da **QueryOver** como base e consegui obter sucesso no que eu desejava, muito obrigado mesmo :)